# SharePoint URL contains extra string "My"

Tags: 2013, my-site

I created a web application then a My Site. When I restore my site, all links contains string "My" and no port in it. How can I remove it?

This link:

`http://siteURL/my/default.aspx` should be `http://siteURL:6060/default.aspx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

someone set it already in Manage Profile Service > User Profile Service > setup my Site (My site HOST)

Changed it to correct URL.